# Oracle 11g Express with Oracle Developer Suite 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
 - Machine: Windows 7 (32bit)
 - Oracle 11g express (32bit downloaded from OTN)
 - Oracle Developer Suite 10g
```

Run SQL From Command line works fine (i can connect sql and use hr/hr or system or sys) without any problem.

When i try to connect Form Builder it gives me following error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
```

I tried to connect form builder with 11g express via:

```
hr/hr@xe (ORA-12154 as mentioned above)
hr/hr (Ora-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error)
```

How to connect developer suite 10g with oracle 11g express and prevent all errors?

Comment: Do you have the XE alias defined properly in your `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\tnsnames.ora c ontains:
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = haroon-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

while same file on devsuitehome_1\network\admin does not contain XE

Comment: But is Forms using the same file, or does it have its own?

Comment: ok - i copied listener.ora and tnsnames.ora from oracle express to devsuitehome (forms etc) and its all fine now!